# Is there a way for StackExchange to accept Launchpad IDs to login systemwide?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stackexchange, launchpad

*In the original, pre-shortened form of the question I was complaining that I can't login some other StackExchange site with my Launchpad ID, providing the screenshot:*

[image]

*Rest was almost like this:*

I would be happy if our leading friends carry this message to StackExchange administration and I hope the people in charge of such things there, will accept this will. [*"will" being to have the ability to use Launcpad IDs for other StackExchange sites.*]

Comment: My lp account auto logs into to other SE accounts, maybe there's a bug? Also, "demand" is a kind of strong word, perhaps you mean "ask nicely"? :)

Comment: @Jorge Castro: For the first part: I'll try to check again from my side even if I don't know what to do to check. For the second part: You are right. Corrected.

Comment: After Jorge Castro's comment I tried more and found that it was my bad. Now it is time to clean, shorten my question and answer my-dumb-self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackExchange **already** accepts Launchpad IDs to login systemwide. In fact the screenshot provided in the question tells all. The questioner (me) should click on the "Confirm and Create New Account" button. "System is trying to make me not to use my launchpad account" type of fear is baseless. If you click that button you are almost automatically registered with the info you provided for your alredy existing Ask Ubuntu account. However, I don't know what happens if one has no Ask Ubuntu account associated with his/her Launchpad account but try to sign in any of StackExchange sites with his/her Launchpad ID.