# Launchpad account recognized on some stackexchanges sites, not all

Tags: support, login, launchpad, openid

### Context

My StackExchange account lists in "My Logins" several providers, including Launchpad.  There is written:

> Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts

### Expected

- When not logged in, I can use Launchpad login on any Stack Exchange sites.
- When logged in via Ask Ubuntu, I am logged in on all Stack Exchange sites.

### Observed

- When not logged in, I can use Launchpad login only on askubuntu.com
- When logged on Ask Ubuntu with Launchpad I am logged in on some sites, but not all.

### Example (steps to reproduce)

For example, after logging in on https://askubuntu.com/ I was logged in on Unix & Linux, Server Fault, Stack Overflow but not Super User. Super User would just say I'm not logged in. Clicking on "log in" would offer some providers, but not Ask Ubuntu.  Reloading the page would not fix.

I restarted Firefox, removed all cookies, only to see that I was still logged in (what the ... ?).

#### (steps to reproduce)

Used the "log out" link then logged in again using launchpad ID on Ask Ubuntu.  There, I see I'm logged in on most on [my accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/1532534/st%C3%A9phane-gourichon?tab=accounts) but not [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  It's strange that this time I'm logged in on Super User, which wasn't the case before.

### Search before you ask

- I have read [Is there a way for StackExchange to accept Launchpad IDs to login systemwide? - Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/592/is-there-a-way-for-stackexchange-to-accept-launchpad-ids-to-login-systemwide) done it long time ago. Not the problem.
- I have read [Can I (and How do I) use my askubuntu account on other Stack Exchange sites? - Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3489/can-i-and-how-do-i-use-my-askubuntu-account-on-other-stack-exchange-sites) . The options on the login page on the network are more restricted than before (e.g. Launchpad not listed on Super User).

### Questions

1. Is there any explanation for the observed behavior?
2. Is the "expected behavior" correct?
3. How to go from the "observed behavior" to the "expected behavior"?

Comment: @muru Thanks for the edit. I spelled the site names as they graphically appear (including lowercase). Could not find official rules. Thanks for improving markup.

Comment: No problem. You can find their proper names in the tour pages... which reminds me that superuser is actually [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

The answer to [Can I (and How do I) use my askubuntu account on other Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3489/) is actually still correct, but Stack Exchange has changed their login page some so it isn't quite clear.

On the login page you need to click "more login options" and then input your launchpad URL in the OpenID field.

[image] [image: enter image description here[2]]

Comment: Thank you. The "more login options" is so discreet that I had not seen it. Experimenting a little more, it seems that logging in on Stack Exchange does log me in on all sites except area51. This will be sufficient in practice. It's even a little more convenient that logging in on askubuntu because login autocompletion doesn't work there while OpenID URL autocompletion works on Stack Exchange. All is not clear but the problem is practically solved. Thanks.